# download images from url to image array and show in table view swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am facing trouble getting image from my json url.

this is my json:

```
"bank_details": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "logo": "http://mortgagemarket.ae/webApi/public/mortgage_bank_icons/noorebank.png",
        "name": abc company

    }
]
```

my swift code to parse the image is this:

```
import UIKit
class BanksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

final let BANKS_URL = "http://www.mortgagemarket.ae/webApi/api/manage_interest_rates"
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var bankicon = [String]()
var bankname = [String]()
var bankid = [Int]()

let stringid: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.displayFromDb()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self


}



func displayFromDb()
{
    let tokensp = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "tokenKey")
    let url = NSURL(string: BANKS_URL+"?token="+tokensp!)

    print(url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as?URL)!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) ->
        Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        {

            print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "bank_details")!)

            if let messageArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "bank_details") as? NSArray
            {
                print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "bank_details")!)

                for message in messageArray
                {
                    if let messageDict = message as? NSDictionary
                    {

                        if let data = data {


                            if let bankname = messageDict.value(forKey: "bank_name")
                            {
                                self.bankname.append(bankname as! String)
                                print(bankname)

                            }


                            if let banklogo = messageDict.value(forKey: "logo")
                            {

                                self.bankicon.append(banklogo as! String)
                                print(banklogo)

                            }

                            if let bankid = messageDict.value(forKey: "id")
                            {
                                self.bankid.append(bankid as! Int)
                                print(bankid)

                            }

                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }


    }).resume()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (bankname.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BanksTableViewCell



  cell.bankicon.image = bankicon[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
    cell.bankname.text = bankname[indexPath.row]


    return (cell)

}

}
```

now When I run this code it is showing blank table cells. I dont know how to get image from url and display the images in table view cell. Please someone help me.
this is my whole code to get the all the json data into table view cell. Please someone help me

Comment: Btw your JSON is not valid

Comment: @Teetz the json is valid

Comment: The JSON is invalid: `Error: Parse error on line 1:
"bank_details": [{ "logo": "http:
--------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'`

Comment: ack, I wish STACKOVERFLOW was more helpful. good question on your end.

Answer (score 0):

imageicon[indexPath.row] `gives a url`String`and not the instance of`UIImage`.` You need to fetch the `image` from server using this `urlString`.

Use **`URLSession`** to fetch the image from server like,

```
if let url = URL(string: imageicon[indexPath.row]) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imageicon.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: this isn't  a recommended approach as this will kepp downloading the same image multiple times when scroll

Comment: It can definitely be saved in the cache or the model. That totally depends upon the OP whether he wants to do that or not. Question is not about caching the downloaded image.

Comment: this is not showing the image :(

Comment: Check if you're getting any error.

Comment: Check if the URL that you're using is a valid one.

Comment: url is fine because i am getting names.

Comment: Can you show the url that you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

Your models should be like this:

```
/// Your response models
struct BankDetails: Codable {
    let bank_details: [ImageUrl]
}

struct ImageUrl: Codable {
    let logo: String
}
```

And then in your cell:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    /// create dataTask for cancel in prepareForReuse function
    private var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    /// Like this
    override public func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        dataTask?.cancel()
    }

    func populate(with model: YourModel) {
        /// You should set url in indexPath of your logo array([ImageUrl])
        let url = model.url /// It's sample url for explain this is an url of your current index model
        if let imageUrl = url {
            downloaded(from: imageUrl)
        }
    }

    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                 let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                 let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.yourImageView.image = image
            }
        }
        dataTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

In your Controller's tableView cellForRowAt function:

```
let model = models[indexPath.row]
cell.populate(with: model)

return cell
```

You can use the above models, and create displayFromDb like this:

```
func displayFromDb() {
    let tokensp = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "tokenKey")
    let url = NSURL(string: BANKS_URL+"?token="+tokensp!)

    if let myUrl = url {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl) { (data, response , error) in      
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let data = try decoder.decode(BankDetails.self, from: data)
            print("my logo array is: \(data.bank_details)")
            // TODO: - So you get urls 

        } catch let err {
            print("Err", err)
        }
    }.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: `bank_details` and `logo` are not `imageUrls` and `url` this won't deocde

Comment: nope. its not working :(

Comment: @johnDoe Please share your final code for better understanding. We can solve this issue together :)

Comment: @EmreCiftci  see the edit please

Comment: Hi @johnDoe please check my edit and don't hesitation for ask question. Let's solve this problem.

Comment: @EmreCiftci I dont have model class

Comment: You can create model structure.

Comment: can you paste the code for my model class here,Because I have never used one before. @EmreCiftci

Comment: Please check my edit @johnDoe. If you have any questions please ask immediately. Enjoy.